# XMLHttpRequest : how to navigate the "Link" header

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, github-api

## Context

I'm using an `XMLHttpRequest` to request a resource from the GitHub API. Since [the response is paginated](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-rest-api#pagination), I want to use the `Link` header that is provided.

When logging `request.getResponseHeader("link")` in the response callback, I get either `null` (if not paginated) or something like:

```
<https://api.github.com/repositories/14173222/forks?sort=stargazers&per_page=100&page=2>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/repositories/14173222/forks?sort=stargazers&per_page=100&page=4>; rel="last"
```

## Question

**Is there an easy way to navigate this returned String without having to parse it?**

Something along the lines of `request.getResponseHeader("link").get("next")` and which would return `https://api.github.com/repositories/14173222/forks?sort=stargazers&per_page=100&page=2`
.

My actual goal is to extract the next page's number (here, for example, I'd like a function which returns `2` since it is the next page to be requested).

Comment: No, there's no native method to do that. You'll have to write your own or search for one of the many libraries and code snippets that do that.

Answer (score 0):

I won't mark this as an accepted answer since it doesn't completely answer the question, but this is nonetheless what I ended up doing:

```
/** Paginated request. Pages index start at 1. */
function request_fork_page(page_number, user, repo, token) {

  // ...

  /* Pagination (beyond 100 forks). */
  const link_header = request.getResponseHeader("link");
  if (link_header) {
    let contains_next_page = link_header.indexOf('>; rel="next"');
    if (contains_next_page !== -1) {
      request_fork_page(++page_number, user, repo);
    }
  }
}
```